# Save matplotlib to variable rather than save as a file

Tags: python, matplotlib, mlops

I want to save a matplotlib figure to a variable so I can pass it to a separate script and save it using output parameters defined there. It is not possible to have this output directory in the script that makes the plots.

Comment: you may use the fig variable that is returned from `fig = plt.figure()`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.